# VirtualBox Drag & Drop

Tags: virtualbox

I have VirtualBox 5.0 and the drag and drop feature is not working even though I enabled the bidirectional. Any way to fix it ? I believe I have downloaded all the required files for the virtual machine

Thanks for your time

Comment: I have run into the same issue, copy and paste works but drag and drop I have never got to work ... ever :(

Comment: Did you install guest addon?

Comment: The thing is that the copy and past is not working as well >:(

Comment: I installed the guest x-11 thing I watched all the video on youtube relating this matter and couldn't solve the issue

Comment: It's not duplicated as that was the old version of VirtualBox

Comment: Did you enabled shared clipboard? If so, and the guest addon installed, and it still doesn't work, that's indeed strange. Please, add to the title that clipboard doesn't work either. Btw, does shared directories work?

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem which I don't know the technical details of with the drag and drop option but you still can use the **shared folders** you can access them by host or virtual OS on virtualbox check the link  [for more details](https://goo.gl/8gXcqu)